# Docker Datacenter on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016, docker-datacenter

I feel like I'm getting mixed signals about Docker DataCenter on Windows Server 2016. There are some notes about it running natively on Windows, but is this so and is there any estimates to when?

Answer (score 2):

It was announced back in September 2016, Read about its official launch here at docker blog

https://blog.docker.com/2016/09/dockerforws2016/

Few things to consider while running Docker on Windows server 2016 :

1. Install the feature "Containers" from adds roles and features .
2. Install the container support, before installing docker you need to install this support.

open powershell and run :

```
Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery -Force
```

3. Install Docker

```
Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider
```

4. Restart your server

```
Restart-Computer -Force
```

you are good to go.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Yes docker enterprise for WS2016 has been announced, but I am asking specifically about DataCenter, which to my understanding, should at some point become available for WS2016

Comment: Yeah Docker datacenter for windows server 2016 is still not confirmed , They announced in last year Nov that Docker Datacenter is soon coming with Docker Datacenter for Windows (Beta) and you can sign up for the beta here –> 
https://goto.docker.com/MicrosoftWindowsServers2016_LP.html